# Why the process $n \mapsto e^{-aT_n}f(X_{T_n})$ is a super martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, exponential-distribution

Let $M := (e^{-aT_n}f(X_{T_n}); \mathcal{F}_n)$, where $a$ is constant, $\mathcal{F}_n$ is appropriately defined filtration and $T_n$ is $n$th jump of an independent (independent of $X_t$) Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ i.e. $T_n$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $1/\lambda$.

Assume that $f(x) \geq \mathbb{E}_x[e^{-aU}f(X_{U})]$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$, where $U$ is independent of $X_t$ and exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $1/\lambda$.

Why does it follow from this inequality that $M$ is indeed a supermartingale? I assume this should be straightforward but I don't see how to apply the definition of a supermartingale here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing an assumption about $X$ being a stationary (strong) Markov process so that:
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X_{t+u})|X_s, s\leq t] = \mathbb{E}_{X_t}[g(X_u)]$$

Also, if the $T_n$ are really jump times of a Poisson process, then the *differences* $T_{n+1}-T_n$ are exponentially distributed with parameter $1/\lambda$, obviously.  I assume this was just a typo and not throwing you off.

With that said, because $T_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, we can write:
$$\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]
= e^{-aT_n}\mathbb{E}[e^{-a(T_{n+1}-T_n)}f(X_{T_{n+1}})|\mathcal{F}_n]
= e^{-aT_n}\mathbb{E}[e^{-aU}f(X_{T_n+U})|\mathcal{F}_n]$$
for $U=T_{n+1}-T_n$.  By the independence of $U$ and the stationary (strong) Markov property for $X$, we have:
$$=e^{-aT_n}\mathbb{E}_{X_{T_n}}[e^{-aU}f(X_U)]$$
and by the hypothesized inequality:

$$\leq e^{-aT_n} f(X_{T_n}) = M_n$$

Comment: Great! Yeah the key thing I was missing is the Markov property. It is indeed assumed.